# Migrating from broken iOS device, from iCloud Back-up

Tags: google-drive, ios

This webpage below explains how to migrate from an iOS device to Android. My problem is that the iOS device doesn't work anymore. Therefore it is not possible to use the procedure explained there. The data on the iPhone is backed up in iCloud. How can we migrate to android from an iCloud backup (for free)? How can i copy the data on iCloud to my Google Drive and then to my new Android phone?
https://www.android.com/switch/

edit: I tried to use the app "MobileTrans" but it doesn't accept the iCloud Password.